# On submit error checks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm checking on submit for required inputs, now everything works like how i want it. Only the error variable acting strange I think it overwrites the error variable every time. What I want is whenever there is an error is most not show the success message. Now it works if only email is valid because thats the last line where var error will be passed.

Current code

```
var error;
contactForm.on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    contactFields.each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0 || $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid red"});
            error = true;
        } else {
            $(this).css({"border" : "2px solid green"});
            error = false;
        }
    }); 
    if(contactName.val().length < 2) {
        contactName.css({"border" : "1px solid red"});
        error = true;
    } else {
        contactName.css({"border" : "2px solid green"});
        error = false;
    }
    var checkmail = $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url : "emailcheck.php",
        data : {email: contactEmail.val()},
        global: false,
        async:false,
    }).responseText;
    if(checkmail === "valid") {
        contactEmail.css({"border" : "2px solid green"});
        error = false;
    } else{
        contactEmail.css({"border" : "1px solid red"});  
        error = true;
    }
    if (!error) {
        $("form").hide(); 
        $(".form-status").html("Successful sended");
    }   
});
```

Now it triggers the `$("form").hide(); $(".form-status").html("Successful sended");` everytime the email is valid even when the other checks return back `error = true`. How do i need to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
var error;
contactForm.on("submit", function(e){
    error = false;
    contactFields.each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0 || $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid red"});
            error = true;
        } else {
            $(this).css({"border" : "2px solid green"});
        }
    }); 
    if(contactName.val().length < 2) {
        contactName.css({"border" : "1px solid red"});
        error = true;
    } else {
        contactName.css({"border" : "2px solid green"});
    }
    var checkmail = $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url : "emailcheck.php",
        data : {email: contactEmail.val()},
        global: false,
        async:false,
    }).responseText;
    if(checkmail === "valid") {
        contactEmail.css({"border" : "2px solid green"});
    } else{
        contactEmail.css({"border" : "1px solid red"});  
        error = true;
    }
    if (!error) {
        $("form").hide(); 
        $(".form-status").html("Successful sended");
    }
    return !error;   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing...
let me know if it worked out

```
var error;
contactForm.on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    contactFields.each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0 || $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid red"});
            error = true;
        } else {
            $(this).css({"border" : "2px solid green"});
            if(!error){error = false;}
        }
    }); 

    if(contactName.val().length < 2) {
        contactName.css({"border" : "1px solid red"});
        error = true;
    } else {
        contactName.css({"border" : "2px solid green"});
        if(!error){error = false;}
    }
    var checkmail = $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url : "emailcheck.php",
        data : {email: contactEmail.val()},
        global: false,
        async:false,
    }).responseText;
    if(checkmail === "valid") {
        contactEmail.css({"border" : "2px solid green"});
        if(!error){error = false;}
    } else{
        contactEmail.css({"border" : "1px solid red"});  
        error = true;
    }
    if (!error) {
        $("form").hide(); 
        $(".form-status").html("Successful sended");
    }   
});
```